# Need to Pass Environment Variables Through Apache Proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, environment-variables

BACKEND: I have Tomcat connected to Apache and JKMount'ed to `webapps.demo.example.com`.

FRONTEND: The primary VirtualHost is setup for `demo.example.com`. I have one application Proxy'd to BACKEND. This works great except the ServerName and ContextPath need to pull from the FRONTEND.

Tried below, following these instructions:
https://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1954/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/example.com"
    ServerName demo.example.com

    ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

    RewriteRule ^ - [E=SERVER_NAME:${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}}]

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass "/Project1/Test" "http://webapps.demo.example.com/Test1"
    ProxyPassReverse /Project1/Test http://%{SERVER_NAME} interpolate

    ErrorLog "/home/logs/httpd/example-error_log"
    CustomLog "/home/logs/httpd/example-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/webapps"
    ServerName webapps.demo.example.com

    JkMount /Test1 worker1
    JkMount /Test1/* worker1

    ErrorLog "/home/logs/httpd/webapps-error_log"
    CustomLog "/home/logs/httpd/webapps-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

When `ProxyPreserveHost On` is added my Proxy'd links return 404 instead of the Test1 Application.

What is the proper way to Proxy, while passing certain environment variables from the FRONTEND server? I am able to change the Test1 Application if absolutely nessesary. But I do need a variable to work with. `Project1` cannot be a hard coded value.

Can mod_proxy_html or mod_headers help here?